# pjax - forward and back buttons. Force full page reload?

Tags: history.js, pjax, popstate

I'm pretty new with ajax and history states. And now I'm doing this site where I load blog posts with **pjax**. Something like [codrops medium style transitions](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/MediumStylePageTransition/). Because I recreated the same effect and didn't use any of codrop's code, I can't get the back and forward buttons to work out. Or maybe I've set up the events all wrong. Or generally thought about it all wrong.

```
// Function to refresh the .current and .next elements
function refreshSelectors(){
    $blogpost_current = $('.current');
    $blogpost_next = $('.next');
};


$_(document).on("click", "*[data-pjax]", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Get url
    var href = $(this).attr('href');

    // Fade out current post
    $blogpost_current.addClass('fade-up-out');

    // Get the difference in height between .next and top of window
    var translateValue = $blogpost_next.get(0).getBoundingClientRect().top;

    // Add easing class on .next to move it to the top.
    $blogpost_next.addClass('easing-upward').css({"transform": "translate3d(0, -" + translateValue + "px, 0"});

    // Remove .next class and set it as current
    $blogpost_next.removeClass('next').addClass('current');

    // After 450ms
    setTimeout(function(){
        // Remove old .current post
        $blogpost_current.remove();

        // Remove easing-upward class on .next
        $blogpost_next.removeClass('easing-upward');

        // Snap it in place
        $blogpost_next.css({"transform": ""});

        // Scroll to top
        $body.scrollTop(0);
        $html.scrollTop(0);

        // Refersh selectorer
        refreshSelectors();

        // Create new .next section, to fill the ajax content into
        $blogpost_current.after('<section class="page next"></section>')

        // Refersh selectorer
        refreshSelectors();

        // Make the pjax call
        $.pjax({url: href, container: $blogpost_next, fragment: ".next", timeout: 2000});

    }, 450)
});
```

So basically, both current and next entries are loaded on the page initially. And the content inside `.next` is hidden. And is only visible when the class is changed to `.current`. Notice that it's only when the animation is complete that the new `.next` is created and filled in by pjax. Maybe I should have used other events instead? And that timer in there could possibly have been put in an actual event or?

Or, maybe it's easiest to have the back and forward buttons actually *reload* the page.

```
$(document).on('pjax:popstate', function(event) { 
    location.reload();
});
```

What would be the best solution? Is this handled by pjax when done correctly? Or would I have to listen to the popstate event to get the correct content? And possibly animate it the other way around?